# Getting error when proguard enabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am getting the following error:

> Can't find common super class of [android/view/View] (with 2 known
>   super classes) and
>   [com/rey/material/widget/ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView] (with 2
>   known super classes)

My build.gradle file is look like this:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
       // shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
       // shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I have added following keep rules inside proguard-rules.pro

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
  public private *;
 }
-keep class com.rey.material.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.rey.material.**
```

How can I solve this issue? Am I missing any keep rules? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please update library version to 1.2.5 and add -keep class com.rey.material.** { ; } -dontwarn com.rey.material.* in proguard. This issue is solved!.